# How to input value from different table range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask how to enter `NULL` in Table 2 with values in `LITHOLOGY` column.

Thanks

Table 1

| LITHOLOGY | SITE_ID | DEPTH_FROM | DEPTH_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BXg | DB-01 | 0.00 | 4.50 |
| BXg2 | DB-01 | 4.50 | 10.00 |
| BXg2 | DB-02 | 4.00 | 10.00 |
| BXg2 | DB-02 | 0.00 | 4.00 |

Table 2

| SITE_ID | DEPTH_FROM | DEPTH_TO | CORE_RECOV | LITHOLOGY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DB-01 | 0.00 | 2.00 | 0.20 |  |
| DB-01 | 2.00 | 4.00 | 0.30 |  |
| DB-01 | 4.00 | 6.00 | 0.22 |  |
| DB-01 | 6.00 | 8.00 | 0.32 |  |
| DB-01 | 8.00 | 10.00 | 0.42 |  |
| DB-02 | 0.00 | 3.00 | 0.12 |  |
| DB-02 | 3.00 | 5.00 | 0.42 |  |
| DB-02 | 5.00 | 10.00 | 0.92 |  |

Comment: this exactly same as your previous closed question. You need improve on the question. Show us what is the expected result and also explain the necessary logic. Also include the query you have tried

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, the below will put NULL in every LITHOLOGY column where LITHOLOGY is not null.

If you want to replace blank fields with null use `WHERE LITHOLOGY = ''` instead

```
UPDATE Table2
SET LITHOLOGY = NULL
WHERE LITHOLOGY IS NOT NULL;
```